# how to put 4 figures upside down with subcaption in acm journal two column template

Tags: floats, acm

how to add pictures like this in ACM ACR this  template https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart.. minipage and subfig subcaption packages are not working in my template
i am getting this error LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.
This is my expected output
[image]

This is the output i am getting following this code:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
\RequirePackage{comment}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}
\RequirePackage{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
    \begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption*{MNIST-O}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption*{F-MNIST}
  \end{minipage} 
  
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
    \caption*{CIFAR-10} 
  \end{minipage}  
  \hfill 
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption*{HP News} 
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Accuracy}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

right now there is no subcaption its fig5, fig6, fig7 and fig8, fig9

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're doing, ideally in the form of a compilable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) (MWE). By the way, the ACM provides *several* templates; it's important to be precise about which document class is actually in use.

Comment: @Mico thanks for feedback ..i updated the question

Comment: Your code still isn't compilable as you're not telling us which packages you load.  (or what the conference name is). Your use of the `\caption*` directive suggest that you are loading the `caption` package. Is this correct? Why are the figure captions in **bold**? Does your code load the `subcaption` package as well?

Comment: You can create a fake `\subcaption` using `\par\vskip\abovecaptionskip \makebox{\linewidth}{(a) CIFAR-10}\par`, but you may need to change the font to match the ACM caption.

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet the requirement

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[acmsmall, screen, ]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption, lipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \title{Title}
    \author{author 1}
    \begin{abstract}
        The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the article.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1][4-6]\par
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
        \end{subfigure}
        % <— this is important. There should be no empty line here. 
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Wow or whatever}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```